# Where do I put my scripts in a Yeoman project when using RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, yeoman

So I am just getting started with Yeoman. I just setup a basic project and I am not sure where to put my scripts. Should I just put stuff in the provided app.js? Or should I make my own files and add them to some build script somewhere or require them somewhere? Any advice is appreciated.

I also don't understand the purpose of this in the app.js file:

```
define([], function() {
return 'Hello from Yeoman!';
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, so you opted to use RequireJS for your project. RequireJS allows you to break your code down in **modules** - not only improving the tidiness of your code (reducing spaghetti code), but also de-cluttering the global namespace.

If you look in your **main.js** file, you'll notice the following:

```
require(['app'], function(app) {
  //use app here
  console.log(app);
});
```

What this does is include **app.js** into your main javascript file and runs it.

Now, where i think you're getting confused, is with the new syntax RequireJS introduces - but essentially **each file** forms a [closure and has its own scope](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/).

Imagine the following:

If you weren't using RequireJs to separate your files, and all the code was in **one single file**. It would look like this:

```
function app () {
    return 'Hello from Yeoman!';
}

console.log(app());
```

You can write whatever you want inside **app.js** as long as it's wrapped with the required RequireJS syntax:

```
define([], function() {
    //Start writing your code here
});
```

And that'll be included in **main.js** and compiled down into one file for production.

The docs for Yeoman are a little sparse at the moment, so i'd recommend you head over to the RequireJS site and [read through their documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) if you're keen on writing modular JavaScript.

You can always choose not to include RequireJS when initialising a new Yeoman project if you don't want/need this functionality.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That does help! I hadn't seen that style of setting up multiple files in js before.